# How can I retrieve data from 2 tables linked via a 3rd "link table" in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Firstly, my apologies as there are similar Q&A's on this website but, I can't get any of the solutions to work.

I want to retrieve a list of all dishes with their details (i.e. name of the dish, and description), and their food items with their details. Excluding any IDs.

I tried (just as a test to retrieve the food & dish names):

```
SELECT dish_name, food_name
FROM dish_food_item_link_tbl, food_item_tbl, dish_tbl
JOIN dish_tbl ON dish_tbl.dish_id =  dish_food_item_link_tbl.dish_id
JOIN food_item_tbl ON  dish_food_item_link_tbl.food_id = food_item_tbl.food_id ;
```

I got the error:
ORA-00904:"DISH_FOOD_ITEM_LINK_TBL"."DISH.ID":invalid identifier

My Code:

```
CREATE TABLE dish_tbl
(
dish_id VARCHAR (3),
dish_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
dish_description VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT dish_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (dish_id)
);

CREATE TABLE food_item_tbl
(
food_id VARCHAR (3),
food_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
food_dietry_type VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL, 
food_unit_price NUMBER (4,2) NOT NULL,
food_date_added DATE NOT NULL, 
food_description VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT food_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (food_id)
);

CREATE TABLE dish_food_item_link_tbl  /* One dish contains 1 to many food_item. One food_item is in 1 to many dish. */
(
dish_id VARCHAR (3),
food_id VARCHAR (3),
FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES dish_tbl(dish_id),
FOREIGN KEY (food_id) REFERENCES food_item_tbl(food_id),
PRIMARY KEY (dish_id, food_id)
);
```

I've populated the tables appropriately. Example:

```
INSERT INTO food_item_tbl VALUES ('F1', 'Chips', 'vegan', 3.99, TO_DATE('17-11-2019','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Finest oven-baked chips');
INSERT INTO food_item_tbl VALUES ('F2', 'Spaghetti Bolognese', 'Not suitable for special diets', 13.99, TO_DATE('01-01-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Made from organic wheat flour and British Beef');
INSERT INTO food_item_tbl VALUES ('F3', 'Lasagne', 'Not suitable for special diets', 10.99, TO_DATE('23-02-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Finest cheese and mince beef');
INSERT INTO food_item_tbl VALUES ('F4', 'Mixed salad', 'vegan', 5.99, TO_DATE('17-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'Mix of premium beans and veg');

INSERT INTO dish_tbl VALUES ('D1', 'Cheese Sandwich Meal', 'Cheese sandwich, chips and salad');
INSERT INTO dish_tbl VALUES ('D2', 'Bolognese Bomb', 'Spaghetti Bolognese, chips and salad');

INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D1', 'F8');
INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D1', 'F4');
INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D1', 'F1');
INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D2', 'F2');
INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D2', 'F4');
INSERT INTO dish_food_item_link_tbl VALUES ('D2', 'F1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the implicit and explicit join syntax; you really should only be using the latter:

```sql
SELECT dish.dish_name, food.food_name
FROM food_item_tbl food
INNER JOIN dish_food_item_link_tbl
    ON link.food_id = food.food_id
INNER JOIN dish_tbl dish
    ON dish.dish_id = link.dish_id;
```

Also note that I am using concise aliases in the above query, which makes it easier to read and debug.

Comment: That's beautiful and concise. Is it possible to stop repetition of the dish_name for each food item that it contains? i.e. If Cheese Sandwich meal contains 3 food items (cheese sandwich, chips, salad) then I only want cheese sandwich written once and the 3 food items written in 3 stacked rows

Comment: @Ash Yes that's possible, but I'm afraid it's a substantially different requirement from what you actually asked above.  Therefore, I would recommend asking a new question.  But someone else may try to answer for you here.

Answer (score 0):

As of having the "cheese sandwich written once" issue, SQL*Plus does it for you - use the `BREAK`.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL>   select d.dish_name, f.food_name
  2      from food_item_tbl f
  3           inner join dish_food_item_link_tbl l on l.food_id = f.food_id
  4           inner join dish_tbl d on d.dish_id = l.dish_id
  5  order by d.dish_name, f.food_name;

DISH_NAME                      FOOD_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Bolognese Bomb                 Chips
Bolognese Bomb                 Mixed salad
Bolognese Bomb                 Spaghetti Bolognese
Cheese Sandwich Meal           Chips
Cheese Sandwich Meal           Mixed salad
```

And this is what `BREAK` does:

```
SQL> break on dish_name
SQL>
SQL> /

DISH_NAME                      FOOD_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Bolognese Bomb                 Chips
                               Mixed salad
                               Spaghetti Bolognese
Cheese Sandwich Meal           Chips
                               Mixed salad

SQL>
```

---

If you want to count number of items, use `count` function. Columns - that aren't aggregated (`dish_name` in this case) must be put into the `group by` clause:

```
SQL> select d.dish_name,
  2         count(*) number_of_food_items
  3    from food_item_tbl f
  4         inner join dish_food_item_link_tbl l on l.food_id = f.food_id
  5         inner join dish_tbl d on d.dish_id = l.dish_id
  6  group by d.dish_name
  7  order by d.dish_name;

DISH_NAME                      NUMBER_OF_FOOD_ITEMS
------------------------------ --------------------
Bolognese Bomb                                    3
Cheese Sandwich Meal                              2

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, adding the Break On statement first works perfectly :)

Comment: An additional question: Instead of displaying the food_name for each dish, how could I count the number of food items and just show the total number of food items in each dish?

Comment: Exactly as you said - you'd *COUNT* them. I edited the answer and added an example. Have a look.